# Can we automate data filters for Excel using Pandas?

Tags: excel, python-3.x, pandas, automation

I want to apply filters to spread sheet using Python, which module is more useful Pandas or any other?

Answer (score 1):

Filtering within your pandas dataframe can be done with loc (in addition to some other methods). What I THINK you're looking for is a way to export dataframes to excel and apply a filter within excel.

XLSXWRITER (by John McNamara) satisfies pretty much all xlsx/pandas use cases and has great documentation here --> https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/.

Auto-filtering is an option :) https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/worksheet.html?highlight=auto%20filter#worksheet-autofilter

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understand your question right. Maybe the combination of `pandas` and 
[`qgrid`](https://github.com/quantopian/qgrid) might help you.

Answer (score 0):

Simple filtering in pandas can be accomplished using the .loc DataFrame method.

```
In [4]: data = ({'name': ['Joe', 'Bob', 'Alice', 'Susan'],
    ...: 'dept': ['Marketing', 'IT', 'Marketing', 'Sales']})

In [5]: employees = pd.DataFrame(data)

In [6]: employees
Out[6]:
    name       dept
0    Joe  Marketing
1    Bob         IT
2  Alice  Marketing
3  Susan      Sales

In [7]: marketing = employees.loc[employees['dept'] == 'Marketing']

In [8]: marketing
Out[8]:
    name       dept
0    Joe  Marketing
2  Alice  Marketing
```

You can also use .loc with .isin to select multiple values in the same column

```
In [9]: marketing_it = employees.loc[employees['dept'].isin(['Marketing', 'IT'])]

In [10]: marketing_it
Out[10]:
    name       dept
0    Joe  Marketing
1    Bob         IT
2  Alice  Marketing
```

You can also pass multiple conditions to .loc using an and (&) or or (|) statement to select values from multiple columns

```
In [11]: joe = employees.loc[(employees['dept'] == 'Marketing') & (employees['name'] == 'Joe')]

In [12]: joe
Out[12]:
  name       dept
0  Joe  Marketing
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an an example of adding an autofilter to a worksheet exported from Pandas using XlsxWriter:

```py
import pandas as pd

# Create a Pandas dataframe by reading some data from a space-separated file.
df = pd.read_csv('autofilter_data.txt', sep=r'\s+')

# Create a Pandas Excel writer using XlsxWriter as the engine.
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('pandas_autofilter.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')

# Convert the dataframe to an XlsxWriter Excel object. We also turn off the
# index column at the left of the output dataframe.
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', index=False)

# Get the xlsxwriter workbook and worksheet objects.
workbook  = writer.book
worksheet = writer.sheets['Sheet1']

# Get the dimensions of the dataframe.
(max_row, max_col) = df.shape

# Make the columns wider for clarity.
worksheet.set_column(0,  max_col - 1, 12)

# Set the autofilter.
worksheet.autofilter(0, 0, max_row, max_col - 1)

# Add an optional filter criteria. The placeholder "Region" in the filter
# is ignored and can be any string that adds clarity to the expression.
worksheet.filter_column(0, 'Region == East')

# It isn't enough to just apply the criteria. The rows that don't match
# must also be hidden. We use Pandas to figure our which rows to hide.
for row_num in (df.index[(df['Region'] != 'East')].tolist()):
    worksheet.set_row(row_num + 1, options={'hidden': True})

# Close the Pandas Excel writer and output the Excel file.
writer.save()
```

Output:

[image]

The data used in this example is [here](https://github.com/jmcnamara/XlsxWriter/blob/master/examples/autofilter_data.txt).